# Best solution to get all parents in all depth

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there any better solution to get all node parents in all depth than this :

```
while (parent != null)
{
    parents.Add(parent);

    parent = await _dbContext.Team
                             .Where(x => x.Id == parent.ParentId)
                             .Include(x => x.Customer)
                             .ThenInclude(x => x.User)
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}

foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    entity.Name = "New Name";
    entity.Customer.Name = "New Customer Name";
    entity.Customer.User.Name = "New User Name";
}

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This works but it can send a million SQL queries on a long-depth tree

Comment: There are ways to structure the data in database so you can query parents at once, or you can possibly write a recursive CTE to return the data. EF by itself to my knowledge doesn’t support it.

Comment: Sounds to be a job for a database using nodes (vertices) and edges (links) instead of traditional relational model.

Comment: There are three methods of querying the database 1) Do what you are currently doing 2) Write a stored procedure in database and return results in one chunk 3) Pull all the _dbContext.Team from database and then get parents in c#.  The best solution depends on the amount of memory used. the amount of data transferred, and the processing time.  Usually a DataBase is run on a fast machine with lots of memory.  So using a stored procedure is usually the best results which can be achieved with Entity (_dbContext) using a RawSQL.